# Any way to get mappings of a label encoder in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I am converting strings to categorical values in my dataset using the following piece of code.

```
data['weekday'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(data.weekday).labels
```

For eg,

```
index    weekday
0        Sunday
1        Sunday
2        Wednesday
3        Monday
4        Monday
5        Thursday
6        Tuesday
```

After encoding the weekday, my dataset appears like this:

```
index    weekday
    0       3
    1       3
    2       6
    3       1
    4       1
    5       4
    6       5
```

Is there any way I can know that Sunday has been mapped to 3, Wednesday to 6 and so on?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The best way of doing this can be to use label encoder of sklearn library.

Something like this:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
list(le.classes_)
le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"])
list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
```

Comment: From what I understand - le.classes_ needs to be instantiated after the desired column is transformed to get the real values, and if you use le.classes_ on say a dataframe that had more than one column encoded say with a lambda function, then le.classes_ only recovers a dictionary mapping of the last column encoded. Why is this?

Comment: is there any way to persist the encoder? so we could deploy it?

Comment: @DendiHandian You could try to save the encoder object using pickle.

Comment: @GaneshTata Yes. I have used it on my project.

Answer (score 120):

You can create additional dictionary with mapping:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data['name'])
le_name_mapping = dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_)))
print(le_name_mapping)
{'Tom': 0, 'Nick': 1, 'Kate': 2}
```

Comment: How can I deal with this for lable encoding across multiple columns?

Answer (score 7):

A simple & elegant way to do the same.

```
cat_list = ['Sun', 'Sun', 'Wed', 'Mon', 'Mon']
encoded_data, mapping_index = pd.Series(cat_list).factorize()
```

and you are **done**, check below

```
print(encoded_data)
print(mapping_index)
print(mapping_index.get_loc("Mon"))
```

Comment: In case you don't know what distinct values are coming in data, creating list of hard coded values might leak. LabelEncoder() however deals with whatever coming in way.

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways of doing this. You can consider `pd.factorize`, `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` etc. However, in this specific case, you have two options which will suit you best:

Going by your own method, you can add the categories:

```
pd.Categorical( df.weekday, [ 
    'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 
    'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 
    'Saturday']  ).labels
```

The other option is to map values directly using a `dict`

```
df.weekday.map({
    'Sunday': 0,
    'Monday': 1,
     # ... and so on. You get the idea ...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I am adding my answer even after lot of answers are there to answer this OP'ed question specifically as:

If have you already label encoded your values as:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit('column-or-list-of-values')
```

You can get back the mapping of value to integer codes as:

```
dict(zip(le.classes_,range(len(le.classes_))))
```

Answer (score 3):

First, make a categorical series:

```
weekdays = pd.Series(['Sun', 'Sun', 'Wed', 'Mon', 'Mon']).astype('category')
```

Then, inspect its "categories":

```
weekdays.cat.categories.get_loc('Sun')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have numerical and categorical both type of data in dataframe 
You can use : here X is my dataframe having categorical and numerical both variables

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

for i in range(0,X.shape[1]):
    if X.dtypes[i]=='object':
        X[X.columns[i]] = le.fit_transform(X[X.columns[i]])
```

Or you can try this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
data = data.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Note: This technique is good if you are not interested in converting them back.

Comment: but the question is precisely on the way back conversion ... :)

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple, they have a built-in function for this.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
..
# your model steps and when you have results
..

prediction_decoded = le.inverse_transform(prediction_encoded)
print(prediction_decoded)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
train['cat'] = train['cat'].map(list(train['cat'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().reset_index().set_index('index').to_dict().values())[0])
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another column with the indexed values after converting from categorical to numeric. Think of it as primary key column.

#new column,index contains converted values of column weekday
data['index'] = pd.Categorical.from_array(data.weekday).labels

#view the corresponding values
df.groupby(['index','weekday']).first()

Answer (score 0):

you can update the 'weekday' column with the mapped values, and the DataFrame will then contain the encoded values in the 'weekday' column.

```py
data['weekday'] = data['weekday'].map({
    'Sunday': 0,
    'Monday': 1,
    'Tuesday': 2,
    'Wednesday': 3,
    'Thursday': 4,
    'Friday': 5,
    'Saturday': 6,
})
```