# How to get mapping of label encoder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encode my data by using `defaultdict`,
this is my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
df_del = df.drop(columns=['DEPTN'])

df_encoded = df_del.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
inverse = df_encoded.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].inverse_transform(x))
```

How to combine this together to see the mapping of values?

Answer (score 0):

a simple straight forward way to print all of the labelEncoder's key-values

```
for i in d:
    print(i)
    print(dict(zip(d[i].classes_, d[i].transform(d[i].classes_))))
```

inspired by this solution:
[Any way to get mappings of a label encoder in Python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196589/any-way-to-get-mappings-of-a-label-encoder-in-python-pandas#42889046)